# Problem with password hashing in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hash, bcrypt

Can someone please help me with hashing passwords? I had working login/register in my express app until I added bcrypt. When I register User, in Database I can see that password is hashed. But when I try to login with normal password, I always get back error that Password is not valid. I think that I have problem in my comparePassword method, but I can't see where. Sending some pictures of my code.

User.js file:
[image]

AuthController.js file:
[image]

I hope this is all what I had to send, if not please ask me for more.

Thank you!

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

this is how you defined the `comparePassword()`

```js
User.prototype.comparePassword=function(password){
     return bcrypt.compareAsync(password,this.password)
}
```

The issue is using "this" keyword. "this" inside function refers to object which the function belongs to. In your code, you call in AuthController.js file inside `login()`. Inside `login()` function "this" will refer to `global` object and since there is no password defined inside `global` object `this.password` will return undefined.

Right before calling, `isPasswordValid`, you can test it `console.log(this.password)` which will return undefined. Instead define `comparePassword` like this:

```js
User.prototype.comparePassword=function(password,savedPassword){
     return bcrypt.compareAsync(password,savedPassword)
}
```

So `isPasswordValid` should be like this:

```
 const isPasswordValid=await user.comparePassword(password,user.password)
```

**Edited:**

Remove the beforeSave or beforeCreate hook. Looks like it is hashing the hashed password.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggest, but I'm still getting same response. I console.log(user.password) before I called if(!isPasswordValid).. I get same password that I get after registering User, but isPasswordValid is still false, I don't know why. And I tried to do this: if(isPasswordValid) {...}.. after sending login request, I got back user with jwt token and everything.. But of course, I can use any password and response will be login successfull

Comment: When I tried to console.log password and user.password, password was like admin12345 and user.password was hashed version of this.. So how am I supposed to fix that?

Comment: @maiiKy that is how it is supposed to be. you dont need to fix anything. Remove the beforeSave or beforeCreate hook. Looks like it is hashing the hashed password.

Comment: Thank you much! I tried to comment beforeCreate, then beforeSave hook but nothing happends.. Then I used inside server.js sequelize.sync({ force: true }) but after that I get every time error that my table dont exist.. I created new database and changed name of it inside .env file.. then I registered Admin and one User and I am able to log in.. Thank you so much again!..